# getElementsByClassName shows undefined value from select box

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select, getelementsbyclassname

I have following code in HTML for my option list:

```html
<p>Choose</p>
<select id="depo" value="depo" name="departs">
  <option value="IT"         name="departs" class="department">IT        </option>
  <option value="Literature" name="departs" class="department">Literature</option>
  <option value="Math"       name="departs" class="department">Math      </option>
  <option value="Biology"    name="departs" class="department">Biology   </option>
  <option value="Physics"    name="departs" class="department">Physics   </option>
</select>

<button class = "button" onclick="form_sub(); return false;">Submit</button>
<p id="show_results"></p>
```

And here's JS code:

```js
function form_sub()
{
  var d_opt = document.getElementsByClassName("department");
  var choosen_dep;
  for(var x = 0; x<d_opt.length; x++)
  {    
    if(d_opt[x] == true)
    choosen_dep = d_opt[x].value;                 
  }
  document.getElementById("show_results").innerHTML="</br>" +choosen_dep+  "</br>";
}
```

Every time I select any option in my select box the value returned in the code is: `undefined` (in the field with the paragraph with the show_results function).
Every time I select any option in my select box the value returned in the code is: `undefined` (in the box with the paragraph with the show_results function).
When I delete my `if(d_opt[x] == true)` the returned value is always equal to the last field in the select box - that is "Physics".

I do not know what the problem is - I tried these two methods but neither of them returns what I selected in the form. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: your HTML is invalid `option` elements can't have a `name` or a `class` attribute

Comment: So should I put class and name in the select element?

Comment: just a name, select items cannot be stylable. The names of all form elements are properties for their parent form

Comment: single select:  `document.querySelector('#depo option:checked')`   multiple select: `document.querySelectorAll('#depo option:checked')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every one of your `d_opt[x]` values is always going to be an HTMLOptionElement object, not a boolean. It makes no sense to compare them to `true`.

To get the selected option, read the `value` of the select element.

```js
function form_sub() {

  var d_select = document.getElementById("depo");
  document.getElementById("show_results").innerHTML = "<br>" + d_select.value + "<br>";

}
```

```html
<select id="depo" value="depo" name="departs">
  <option value="IT" name="departs" class="department">IT</option>
  <option value="Literature" name="departs" class="department">Literature</option>
  <option value="Math" name="departs" class="department">Math</option>
  <option value="Biology" name="departs" class="department">Biology</option>
  <option value="Physics" name="departs" class="department">Physics</option>
</select>

<button class="button" onclick="form_sub(); return false;">Submit</button>
<p id="show_results"></p>
```

Also note that the *start* tag for the `br` element is mandatory but the *end* tag is forbidden. You are trying to insert end tags without start tags.

Comment: Thanks for comment. So I can't use getElementsByClassName in select box? Because the values I'm outputting are always "undefined" even if I wrote it the same way as you did in your response.

Comment: @MagicMan You may want to provide a [mre] of that.

Comment: @iota I know that getElementsById is array-like object so I need a loop to go through all the elements. But I don't know how to extract the selected option and return it. I tried everything, but it either returns undefined, or just the last element in the select box - Physics. How to get the selected value?

Comment: @Quentic do you know how to do this with the use of getElementsByClassName?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. Enclose your code in form tags

```html
<body>
        <p>Choose</p>
        <form name = "deps">
<select id="depo" name="departs">
  <option value="IT"        >IT        </option>
  <option value="Literature">Literature</option>
  <option value="Math"      >Math      </option>
  <option value="Biology"   >Biology   </option>
  <option value="Physics"   >Physics   </option>
</select>

<button class = "button" onclick="form_sub(); return false;">Submit</button>
<p id="show_results"></p>
        </form>

<script>
 function form_sub()
{
  var d_opt = document.deps.departs.value;                
  document.getElementById("show_results").innerHTML="</br>" +d_opt+  "</br>";
}
</script>
    </body>
```

Comment: your HTML is invalid option elements can't have a name or a class attribute

Comment: run code snippet it works for what he asked

Comment: of course that this code can be accepted by browsers, this does not mean that this HTML code complies with W3C standards, and it remains invalid